# Runtime Error 1004: SaveCopyAs not letting to overwrite existing files

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do SaveCopyAs to a different destination through a button click. When I execute the code it gives me the error in the following code. Any ideas or suggestions on how to get rid of this ?

```
   Application.DisplayAlerts= False       
   ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs FileName:="W:\..\..\..\" & FileName1 & "-" & "Audit checklist" & ".xlsm"
   Application.DisplayAlerts= True
```

Comment: SaveCopyAs doesn't have a FileFormat parameter, I believe. You can only save to the same format.

Comment: I modified my question since I made changes on code based on suggestions. Now I get different error

Answer (score 2):

The [SaveCopyAs method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835014.aspx) only takes one parameter - `Filename`

Leave out the `FileFormat` and `CreateBackup` arguments and everything should work OK. If you do want to change the file format then use the [SaveAs method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) instead

Comment: In my case, I have a requirement to use SaveCopyAs . I removed the Fileformat and CreateBackup . I get the run time error 1004 saying the filename already exists. I need to overwrite the existing file without showing any alerts.

Comment: If you need to use `SaveCopyAs` then I think your only option is to use the filesystem to rename or delete the existing file before saving the new copy. There's no way to have the `SaveCopyAs` method automatically overwrite an existing file